# how to import data from excel sheet into relational tables at the same time

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, many-to-one

i am trying to import excel sheet lock like the image 
[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ri40.png)
into 3 tables that have 1 to many relationship 
like these 
[the tables i want to import to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezBjR.png) 
i can import the table as it is but it will be bad practice 
please help me with this

i looked in stack overflow for answers but i didn't fine any 
it may be my bad question

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import xlrd

class SchoolProjict(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.app_data = {"name": tk.StringVar(),
                         }
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,  SetingPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, classname):
        for page in self.frames.values():
            if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
                return page
        return None

def printingstuff(var1):
    print (var1)

def printontherthing(page_class):
    print(page_class)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lablel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Main Page")
        lablel.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Siting", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(SetingPage))
        button2.pack()

class SetingPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        lablel = tk.Label(self, text = "Siting Page")
        lablel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.text1 = tk.Entry(self)  #<== i want to show the path of the file i am going to open Here after i select it from openfile 
        self.text1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.text1.focus()
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "print text1", command = lambda: printingstuff(self.text1.get()))
        button1.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="open file", command= self.load_file, width=10)
        button2.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Main Page", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button4.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Creat Database", command = self.CreatTable)
        button4.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

    def load_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel file", "*.xls"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if fname:
            try:
                # print(fname)
                value = str(fname)
                page_var = self.controller.get_page("SetingPage")
                page_var.text1.insert(0, value)
                return

            except:                    
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
            return

    def CreatTable(self):
        loc = (self.text1.get())
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(1)

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("exeldata.db")
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.wkb = wb
        self.sh = sheet

        self.cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gradelevel(
            GlId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            GradNumber text)""")

        self.cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classnumber(
            CID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            GradID INTEGER, 
            ClassNumber text,
            FOREIGN KEY(GradID) REFERENCES gradelevel(GlId))""")

        self.cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studintinfo(
            StID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            StudintID text,
            StudintName text,
            MobileNumber text,
            ClassID INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY(ClassID) REFERENCES classnumber(CID))""")

        print ("Table created")

        for sheet in wb.sheets():
            number_of_rows = sheet.nrows

        for r in  range(4, number_of_rows):    # <== this code good only for 1 tabl this dose not work with the 3 tables i did 
            mobile = self.sh.cell_value(r, 1)
            claasn = self.sh.cell_value(r, 2)   
            greadn = self.sh.cell_value(r, 3)
            studintn = self.sh.cell_value(r, 4)
            studinti = self.sh.cell_value(r, 5)

            self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO gradelevel(GradNumber)VALUES(?)",(greadn,))
            greadID = self.cur.lastrowid
            self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO classnumber(ClassNumb, GradID)VALUES(?,?)",(claasn, greadID))
            classnID = self.cur.lastrowid
            self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO studintinfo(StudintID, StudintName, MobileNumber, ClassID)VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(studinti, studintn, mobile, classnID))

            self.conn.commit()
        print ("Data inserted")


        self.CloseConnection()

    def CloseConnection(self):
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()
        print ("Connection Closed")

app = SchoolProjict()
app.mainloop()
```

also i am new to programming 
thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer some where in this site 
and it is like this

```
self.cur.execute("SELECT GlId FROM gradelevel WHERE GradNumber = ? ", (greadn,)) 
            rows = self.cur.fetchone()
            if rows:
                GreadLvl_ID = rows[0] 
            else:
                self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO gradelevel(GradNumber)VALUES(?)",(greadn,))
                self.cur.execute("SELECT GlId FROM gradelevel WHERE GradNumber = ? ", (greadn,)) 
                rows = self.cur.fetchone()
                GreadLvl_ID = rows[0]
                greadID = self.cur.lastrowid


            self.cur.execute("SELECT CID FROM classnumber WHERE ClassNumb = ? AND GradID = ?", (claasn, GreadLvl_ID))
            rows1 = self.cur.fetchone()
            if rows1:
                class_ID = rows1[0]
            else:
                self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO classnumber(ClassNumb, GradID)VALUES(?,?)",(claasn, GreadLvl_ID))
                self.cur.execute("SELECT CID FROM classnumber WHERE ClassNumb = ? AND GradID = ?", (claasn, GreadLvl_ID))
                rows1 = self.cur.fetchone()
                class_ID = rows1[0]
                classnID = self.cur.lastrowid


            self.cur.execute("SELECT StID FROM studintinfo WHERE StudintID = ? AND ClassID = ?", (studinti, class_ID))
            rows2 = self.cur.fetchone()
            if rows2:
                studint_ID = rows2[0]
            else:
                self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO studintinfo(StudintID, StudintName, MobileNumber, ClassID)VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(studinti, studintn, mobile, class_ID))
                self.cur.execute("SELECT StID FROM studintinfo WHERE StudintID = ? AND ClassID = ?", (studinti, class_ID))
                rows2 = self.cur.fetchone()
                studint_ID = rows2[0]
```